# C# - Pl/SQL Problem with out parameter in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
    PROCEDURE semifinished_lable_data(p_piece_num_id     IN INTEGER,
                                        p_piece_id         OUT STRING,
                                        p_tickness         OUT NUMBER)
   IS begin
    select p_piece_id,p_tickness into p_piece_id,p_tickness from piece p where p.piece_num_id=p_piece_num_id;
   end;
```

I've executed it from the database and it worked perfectly. When I execute it from c# app I don't get any value back.

Then when I researched the problem , I added that : **cmd.BindByName = true** 
But this time i got the following error

> multiple instances of named argument in list

C# codes :

```
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
            var seciliProsedur = "QUA_PRINTING.semifinished_lable_data";
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = seciliProsedur;
            cmd.BindByName = true;
            object piece_num_id = gridViewMain.GetFocusedRowCellValue(gridViewMain.FocusedColumn);
 OracleParameter PAR_ID1 = new OracleParameter();
            PAR_ID1.ParameterName = "p_piece_id ";
            PAR_ID1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
            PAR_ID1.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            PAR_ID1.Value =piece_num_id;
            PAR_ID1.Size = 100;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(PAR_ID1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_piece_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_tickness", OracleDbType.Double,200, null, ParameterDirection.Output);

 conn.Open();


            var da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `PAR_ID1.ParameterName = "p_piece_id ";` has to be
`PAR_ID1.ParameterName = "p_piece_num_id";`

Comment: Yes , I fix it but execute it from c# app I don't get any value back again.

Comment: Your parameters / data types etc doesn't seems to be "proper", names not matching, lot of places to look for. Check the values of variables are there before execution. If still cannot use `SQL Profiler` to see what is the query executed in the server.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I never used `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Try this

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
seciliProsedur = "BEGIN QUA_PRINTING.semifinished_lable_data(:p_piece_num_id  , :p_piece_id, :p_tickness); END;"

OracleParameter PAR_ID1 = new OracleParameter();
PAR_ID1.ParameterName = "p_piece_num_id";
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_piece_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters("p_piece_id").DbType = DbType.Varchar2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_tickness", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 240, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters("p_tickness").DbType = DbType.String;
```

I think you must set `DbType` and `OracleDbType` property.

Then another problem of your code is

```
var da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Your procedure does not return any resultSet (i.e. RefCursor), thus above commands do not work. Use

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```